# Javascript - limit characters only on first paragraph

Tags: javascript

I have a a div with multiple p elements within it. I wanted to know how I can limit the character length of the first p element within each div of the same class.

HTML

```
<div class="el">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates natus dignissimos architecto deserunt totam ullam, nulla ipsum cumque alias possimus dicta officiis provident mollitia modi tempore officia porro tenetur dolor.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias quidem, ad doloribus reiciendis debitis sit suscipit est cumque voluptates corporis adipisci consectetur, perspiciatis quo pariatur minima inventore omnis deleniti assumenda!</p>
</div>
```

Javascript (so far)

```
var quote = document.querySelectorAll('.el');

for (var i=0, len=quote.length; i < len; i++) {

  var text = quote[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML;
  console.log(text);

  if(text.length > 150) {
    console.log("condition met");
    text = text.substring(0,150) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>';
  }
}
```

I think I'm right up until I try to edit the length of text itself. But help would be appreciated along with explanation of what I'm doing wrong. I've set up a fiddle [for your convenience](https://jsfiddle.net/vdecree/gemszha5/).

Comment: try `quote[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = text.substring(0,150) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

Check this i have checked all p element length

```
  var quote = document.querySelectorAll('.el p');

for (var i=0, len=quote.length; i < len; i++) {

  var text = quote[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(text);

  if(text.length > 150) {
    console.log("condition met");
    text = text.substring(0,150) + ' <a href="#">Read more</a>';
    quote[i].innerHTML = text;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I think it's the last parts of the script that are the problem

Comment: @Doidgey i have changed check

Answer (score 0):

just edit your script as follow:

```js
if(text.length > 150) {
    console.log("condition met");
    text = text.substring(0,150) + '<a href="#">Read more</a>';
    quote[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML= text; // update your element
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the suggestions working as I wanted although the they did lead me to this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gemszha5/3/).

Js:

```
var quote = document.querySelectorAll('.el');

for (var i=0, len=quote.length; i < len; i++) {

  var text = quote[i].firstElementChild;

  if(text.innerHTML.length > 200) {
    text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0,200) +  '... <a href="/page-name/">Read more</a>';
  }
}
```